# Ionic slide menu second level, missing back button

Tags: ionic-framework

Does anyone know how can I add a back button to the second level? In my example I need the back button when I'm on the "Settings" page:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="goBack()">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="primary"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left" class="side-menu" slide-along offset="-15">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
        <ul class="list">
            <a href="#/event/settings" class="item" menu-close>Settings</a>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

If I remove `menu-close` from the button, it's acting weird.